# DRF: Simple Switch for a choice field in model via router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to build an `APIView` that can turn on power in a store so to say ...
Can I do it using a `router`?

model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    C = [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
    name = models.IntegerField("name", max_length=60)
    power_state = models.PositiveIntegerField("current state", default=0, choices=C)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

view:

```
class OnOff(APIView):
    def patch(self, request):
        store = Store.objects.get(pk = request.user.id)
        return Response("switched")
```

I am new to DRF and I do not know if I need a serializer here. The interface I see looks like this:

[image]

while I was hoping for a simple dropdown between 0 and ... 3 in this case. Also how would the `router` have to be registered? Right now I put a path in the urls.py:

```
path('test/', views.OnOff.as_view(), name = "on-off"),
```

which means it will not be listed under `127.0.0.1:8000/api/` which would be nice.

I tried using (but 404):

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
...
router.register(r'onoff', views.OnOff, basename = "onoff")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.StoreView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    url('^api/', include(router.urls)), 
    ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The DRF router generates REST style urls and this API does not appear to be REST-ful in the standard sense. ie. list all the objects and detail single objects. [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage).

To add the /api/ using the path method:

```
path('api/test/', views.OnOff.as_view(), name = "on-off"),
```

if you want to just quickly get you API working via the built in interface, add a post method.

```
class OnOff(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        store = Store.objects.get(pk = request.user.id)

        ... sudo code to save the on-off value sent from the interface ...
        store.power_state = request.data.get('on-off', 0)
        store.save()

        return Response("switched")
```

To use the DRF router, a Viewset is required.

The `router.url` propertyu is list of urls that can be included in the main urls.py

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
import .views

app_name = 'on-off'

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'onoff', views.OnOffViewset)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**views.py**

```
class OnOffViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        # in this case the pk is a user.id
        store = Store.objects.get(pk = request.user.id)

        ... sudo code to save the on-off value sent from the interface ...
        store.power_state = request.data.get('on-off', 0)
        store.save()
        return Response({'status': store.power_state})
```

Projects main urls.py
path('api/', include('onoff.urls', namespace='on-off')),

Comment: I will try that, thanks. Can you please also show me how to add the api using the `router.register()` method (I already have the `path` method implemented, but maybe that was not clear from my post.

Comment: You are suggesting `update`to update a single record of `Store` (`power_state` in my case).
Please help me understand: When I implement the `router` the way you suggest, the route does not show up in the `/api/` overview page. I guess this is because there is no defined.
I defined  `get_queryset` method, but the route nevertheless does not show up - and if I call it by url (`/api/onoff/`) I can see in the 404 message that DRF looks for the `-detail` view: `^api/ ^onoff/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='onoff-detail']`. Very much appreciate your hep! Also DRF needed `base_name`.

Comment: Did you include the apps urls.py in the projects main url patterns?

Comment: When I included `path('api/', include('appname.urls', namespace='appname))` (I used `app_name = `appname` in the apps `url.py`) in the projects `url.py` I run into two issues: `127.0.0.1:8000/api` leads to the main page now, (I can still call a API with the correct endpath) and DRF still wants me to provide a `base_name` for the `router` - also there is already a `path('', include('appname.urls'))`.

Comment: The /api/ is not automatically added by the router.  Only include it once, but add the path as you like.